# How to set the weights in GLM where the response is variance?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, variance, weighted-regression

I have observations that are sample variances from a design with 2 factors, 2 levels in each. Although I do not observe the samples according to which these sample variances are computed, I do know the sample sizes.

I want to fit a glm to these data - the response being the sample variances (I think the gamma family is appropriate in this situation) and since the accuracy of a sample variance depends on the sample size I would like to take that into account. I think that using the weights option is probably the way to go but I'm not sure exactly which weights to use. I know that in a glm fitted to proportions the sample sizes (number of trials) are used as weights but I think this is a different situation. Maybe the weights need to be some scaling of the sample sizes?